# I can't copy the entire cookie area inside the code

Tags: html, css, session-cookies

Friends,

I'm creating a website with a page builder, and I share some cookies on it.

I tried to create this code so that users can more easily copy and paste the cookie.

However, I can only copy the first few characters of the cookie.

Look at the pictures, I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Sorry, I'm new to this area.

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer.css" />
    <title>Javascript - Copy to Clipboard</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="texto"
      id="texto"
      readonly
      placeholder="Digite alguma coisa"
      value=`
    "[
    {
        
    {
           [    {        
        "domain": "teste.pro",
        "hostOnly": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "name": "wordpress_test_cookie",
        "path": "/",
        "sameSite": null,
        "secure": false,
        "session": true,
        "storeId": null,
        "value": "WP%20Cookie%20check"
    },
    {
        "domain": "teste.pro",
        "expirationDate": 1708729370.70298,
        "hostOnly": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "name": "wp-settings-time-1",
        "path": "/",
        "sameSite": null,
        "secure": true,
        "session": false,
        "storeId": null,
        "value": "1677193564"
    }
]
 "
   ` />
    <button onclick="copiarTexto()">Copiar</button>

    <script>
      function copiarTexto() {
        let textoCopiado = document.getElementById("texto");
        textoCopiado.select();
        textoCopiado.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
        document.execCommand("copy");
        alert("O texto é: " + textoCopiado.value);
      }
    </script>

    <div class="footer" id="footer"></div>
    <script src="footer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtA7J.jpg)

i want to be able to copy all the cookie

I want to be able to copy the entire cookie, not just those first few characters.

Comment: It looks like the issue with your code is that the cookie value is not properly enclosed in quotes within the value attribute of the input element.

Comment: Use a single quote : ' character instead of a  backtick `

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your attention, the problem was simple, I put the single quotes and it worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to extract the "value=" from another external location? For example.

I have a text in OneDrive in txt, I want the "value" to extract the information from that text.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer.css" />
    <title>Javascript - Copy to Clipboard</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="texto"
      id="texto"
      readonly
      placeholder="Digite alguma coisa"
      value=""

    <button onclick="copiarTexto()">Copiar</button>

    <script>
      function copiarTexto() {
        let textoCopiado = document.getElementById("texto");
        textoCopiado.select();
        textoCopiado.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
        document.execCommand("copy");
        alert("O texto é: " + textoCopiado.value);
      }
    </script>

    <div class="footer" id="footer"></div>
    <script src="footer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```